# Drop-down not working in ToSelectList extension method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a nullable enum that, unlike others on the same page, doesn't work. I have an enum, `Title` whereby using the extension method will help to populate a drop-down list on the page. Here's what the ViewBag declaration looks like:

```
ViewBag.TitleList = EnumExtensions.ToSelectList<Title>("[select]");
```

Now, perhaps someone could explain it to me, but this is where the black magic happens when it comes to binding in MVC. If the page is invalid when calling `if(ModelState.IsValid)` then upon re-rendering the screen, the above statement is called again. However this time, the correct drop-down item will be selected (dependent on which one you had selected at the time).

Digging deeper, this is the method declarations:

```
    public static SelectList ToSelectList<TEnum>(string nullEntry = null) where TEnum : struct
    {
        return ToSelectList<TEnum>(nullEntry, null);
    }


    public static SelectList ToSelectList<TEnum>(string nullEntry = null, string selectedValue = null) where TEnum : struct
    {
        var enumType = typeof(TEnum);
        var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType).OfType<TEnum>();
        List<SelectListItem> items =  ToSelectList<TEnum>(values, nullEntry, selectedValue);
        SelectList sl = new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text", selectedValue);
        return sl;
    }

    public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, string nullEntry, string selectedValue = null)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items;

        if ((typeof(T).IsEnum))
        {
            items = enumerable.Select(f => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = f.GetDescription(),
                Value = f.ToString(),
                Selected = f.ToString() == selectedValue
            }).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            items = enumerable.Select(f => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = f.ToString(),
                Value = f.ToString()
            }).ToList();
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nullEntry))
        {
            items.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Text = nullEntry, Value = "" });
        }

        return items;
    }
```

There's just some overloads to handle random cases, although presumably some of these won't be needed.

As I say, the correct item will be selected for other enumerations, but for this particular one, Title, it will not. Here's the enum declaration:

```
public enum Title
{
    Mr,
    Miss,
    Mrs,
    Ms
}
```

And finally, the declaration using `DropDownListFor` on the page itself;

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Title, (SelectList)ViewBag.TitleList)
```

The problem is that when I first visit the page, the selected item is always "[select]" (when the provided enum value is null in the model). However, the model property `Title` *definitely* has a value set, and the `SelectedItem` property is set for the drop-down list too, but on screen, it defaults to "[select]" which is unexpected.

Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't understand from your question what actually is not working.

Comment: I have a habit of doing that, sorry! Amended the last paragraph.

Comment: Could you show the controller action that is serving this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be because of the name `Title`? Try changing it to another name just to see.

Comment: Good idea, will have a try shortly.

Comment: Bang on the money. I've had this issue before with other enums. Will accept once SO lets me in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try adding String.Empty so it the drop down list will default to a blank

> @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Title, (SelectList)ViewBag.TitleList, String.Empty)